# value functions of two maximization problems

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, optimization

Let $U,V$ be two real-valued random variable, and let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a measurable function. Consider the following two values:

\begin{equation}
V_1=\sup\{\mathbb E((V-f(y(U,V)))(y(U,V)-U))| y:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R \: measurable\} \\
V_2=\mathbb E(\sup_{y\in\mathbb R}(V-f(y))(y-U))
\end{equation}
Clearly, $V_2 \geq V_1$. I am wondering whether they are equal to each other. More specifically, I will assume the problem with value $V_1$ admits a maximizer. What I can show right now is that $V_1=V_2$ provided $f$ is continuous. However, I am not sure whether it is the case if $f$ is only measurable. I would pretty much like to have a positive answer, but a counter-example will be equally appreciated! Thanks!

---

In general, my problem can be formulated as follows: Let $X$ be a random variable with value in $\mathbb R^2$, and let $G:\mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function which is continuous in the first argument and measurable in the second(i.e., a Caratheodory function). Assume the partial maximization $x\mapsto \sup_yG(x,y)$ is measurable(which is clearly the case if $G(x,y)=(x_1-f(y))(y-x_2)$). I am considering the values given by

\begin{equation}
V_1=\sup\{\mathbb E(G(X,y(X))| y:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R \: measurable\} \\
V_2=\mathbb E(\sup_{y\in\mathbb R}G(X,y))
\end{equation}
I would like to know if these two values are the same or not, assuming problem $V_1$ admits a maximizer.

Comment: What's the condition on $y$ in the definition of $V_1$? A function of some kind? Of what?  Your notation is unclear to me.

Comment: I edit my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks.  Are you sure you want $G(x,y)$ to be continuous and measurable in $(x,y)$ instead of measurable and continuous?

Comment: the function $G$ in my original problem is $G(x,y)=(x_1-f(y))(y-x_2)$, so I think yes.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Can you please fill in some detail in the "clearly" bit in the 2nd part.

Comment: $G(x,y)=yx_1+f(y)x_2-yf(y)-x_1x_2$, which is continuous in $x$ and measurable in $y$, and $\sup_yG(x,y)=\sup_y\{yx_1+f(y)x_2-yf(y)\} -x_1x_2$, which is a convex function plus a measurable function, so measurable. Hope this make things clear.

Comment: I appreciate you pointing out the ill-posedness of my question. Please do let me know if there is anything that does not make sense to you. I really want to make everything clear.

Comment: Why is $G(x,y)$ convex?  Convex in $y$?

Comment: I didn't say $G(x,y)$ is convex. What I am saying is $\sup_yG(x,y)$ is measurable, so that expectation in $V_2$ is well-defined.

Comment: I posted the question on math overflow and received an answer which I think is correct. The link to the MO post is https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284131/measurable-selection-and-values-of-optimization-problem/284159#284159

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-answer, focused on the second, or $G(x,y),$ formulation.

My first, naive, reaction is, in the expectation defining $V_2$, there is, for $\epsilon>0$  an $X$-dependent $y_0(X)$ such that for almost all $X$ we have $G(X,y_0(X))>\sup_y G(X,y)-\epsilon.$  Let *that* function $y_0$ (or a limit as $\epsilon\to0$) be the desired measurable $y$ in the definition of $V_1$.  But, of course, we don't know that $y_0$ is measurable, even though (apparently) the map $\gamma:x\mapsto \sup_y G(x,y)$ is, or else the OP wouldn't be able to take its expectation.

That led to the self-realization that I don't actually know *why* $\gamma$ is measurable, which is to say, why $V_2$ is well-defined.  Maybe it comes from the assumption that $G$ is a Caratheodory function.  Maybe that argument contains a clue to the OP's problem.

Said differently: for $\epsilon>0$ and almost all $X$ there is a *set* $S_\epsilon(X)$ such that for all $u\in S_\epsilon(X)$ we have $G(X,u)>\sup_y G(X,y)-\epsilon$, and what is desired is a measurable selection $y_0$ of elements from $S_\epsilon(X),$ one per $X$ value: for almost all $X$ we have $y_0(X)\in S_\epsilon(X).$  A glance at section 6.9, "Measurable choice theorems" in Bogachev's *Measure Theory* (vol 2, pp. 33-43) shows that this kind of question can be complicated.

So maybe the OP can supply an argument for why his $V_2$ is well-defined, and we can go on from there.

Comment: You are right the problem is ill-posed without measurability of $\sup_yG(x,y)$. In my original question, this map is a convex function(as being supremum of linear function in $x$) plus a measurable function, therefore measurable. Maybe one can start from this particular case, then go to the general case with appropriate measurability assumption imposed on $\sup_yG(x,y)$?

Comment: There is no mention of *convex* in your original question.  Why don't you ask your  real question, precisely  stating what it is and what the assumptions are, and edit your post accordingly, completely rewriting it?  (And, if possible, omitting extraneous detail.)

Comment: More directly: please don't ask ill-posed questions.

Comment: My real question is precisely the 1st part of my post. The 2nd part is a general form of the particular question in the 1st part. It was my bad for not imposing any assumption on the function $G$, which made the question ill-posed. Very sorry for this confusion.

Comment: I do believe my question in the first part of the post is well-posed, with no measurability issue.

Comment: I edit my post accordingly. Thank you!